# Getting mean of particular columns in data frame based on list of column names

Tags: r

I need to modify some R code that someone else wrote to make it more general.  This code was written to run on specific data with specific column names, but they want to be able to run the same code on a totally different data set.  This means I need to make the code take vectors of column names and use those wherever specific columns are referenced.

As a simple example, suppose I have a data frame where each row is an individual's age, gender, and a bunch of other observed values about that person.  So this is my data:

```
df <- data.frame(age=sample(20:30, 500, T), gender=sample(c("M", "F"), 500, T), 
                 A=sample(1:100, 500, T), B=sample(3:50, 500, T), 
                 C=sample(2:6, 500, T))
```

Then I want to, for each pair of age and gender, get the mean values for the other variables.  In the specific case, I want to do:

```
df.means <- ddply(df, .(age, gender), summarize, mean_A = mean(A), mean_B = mean(B))
```

However, what I want is to be given vectors, `id_vars <- c("age", "gender")` and `covariates <- c("A", "B", "C")` and have `ddply` get the means of the covariates for each combination of `id_vars` without hard-coding the variable names. I get that I can just replace `.(age, gender)` with `id_vars`, but I'm not sure what to do about taking the means.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
res <- df %>% 
          group_by_(.dots=id_vars) %>% 
          summarise_each_(funs(mean), covariates)

head(res,3)
#    age gender        A        B        C
#  1  20      F 39.35294 24.70588 3.235294
#  2  20      M 59.14286 25.35714 4.428571
#  3  21      F 54.19048 26.66667 3.809524
```

where

```
id_vars <- c("age", "gender")
covariates <- c("A", "B", "C")
```